# Does Linux command libboost-all-dev install and compile the header-only libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, boost

On Ubuntu there is a command to install boost libraries which is something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

does this command also install **and compile** the header-only libraries?

If not, what other terminal command would I need to execute so that I can install the FULL set of boost libraries?

My ultimate aim is to know which linux terminal commands I need to install (and have available) to obtain all of the boost libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As is implied by "header only", one does not need to compile the header-only libraries. They're just headers.

Now, the libbost-all-dev package does install those libraries which need compilation (in addition to the header-only libs), but it does not compile them on the spot. Ubuntu is a so-called binary distribution, which means that it distributes packages in compiled form. Apt downloads the binaries and installs them immediately. This is in contrast to e.g. Gentoo which is a source distribution (and compiles everything on your machine).

In short, no further commands are necessary. Installing libbost-all-dev will install all available Boost libraries on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions, as posed, makes no sense.

The Debian / Ubuntu *package* `libboost-all-dev` has dependencies, and those dependencies do include the few binary library packages (eg Boost Thread, the formatting parts of Boost DateTime, etc pp).  All those will get installed.

And yes, the intent of *this* meta package is to install the rest of the Boost development environment.

But it does not compile anything. All Debian / Ubuntu packages are pre-generated and built-offline and "just installed" at your end.

Comment: Apologies I thought the boost "bjam.exe process" for Windows compiled additional code- hence my wording of the question.

Comment: No worries. Binary deb packages are super useful precisely because "no assembly required".

Comment: It does. Bjam on Ubuntu also compiles additional code, when you install from source. When you install using apt, you aren't installing from source. You're installing the compiled files which some package maintainer created by compiling from source.

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect the content of a package by browsing the [online database](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libboost-all-dev).

But if you are only interested in header-only libraries I suggest to download the latest version of the boost libraries right from the official website; you should also learn how to build boost from the source because it's a know-how that you are very likely to use in a near future if you are relying on that library.

An equivalent step to browsing the online database, it's about using the following command

```
apt-cache show <package>
```

so, in your case

```
apt-cache show libboost-all-dev
```

and this will give you a very specific idea about what you are about to install.

Comment: No i'm not interested in just the header-only libraries- I wanted to obtain the header-only and the non-header-only libraries.

Comment: @user997112 than you will be fine with that package